# C#: Interpolated Strings- Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#

[image]I am looking at this example from the google cloud platform.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples

Specifically:

```
public void DownloadStream(string bucketName)
{
    StorageService storage = CreateStorageClient();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        storage.Objects.Get(bucketName, "my-file.txt").Download(stream);

        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());

        Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded my-file.txt with content: {content}");
    }
}
```

**Console.WriteLine($** keeps giving me an error. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and cant seem to get this to work properly. Instead what i have to do is remove the dollar sign and + content as a variable.

I read this is a new syntax for C# version 6? Am i missing something? - Cant do this on Visual studio 2013?

Thanks for your responses!

I have updated my solution to provide a picture of the error. All it says is ) Expected.

It seems it does not recognize the dollar sign.

Comment: You need VS 2015 to target C# 6 to utilize string interpolation.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, I have updated the question so you can see the error better. Hopefully you can remove the negatives. Thanks!

Comment: @ADL I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 does not support interpolated strings. This is a feature from 2015.

Answer (score 10):

In order to use the new C# 6 capabilities you need to use VS 2015 instead. You can avoid that error by using

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Downloaded my-file.txt with content:{0}", content));
```

which is the C# 5 style of doing that.

Comment: Thanks! I kinda figured that's why.